# How to return non-unique join table records in sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm Querying a specific 'Student', including a many - to many relationship for companies yet dupes are not coming back for records with the same studentId, and companyId. The join table does also have a primary key with id on it.

Look at the line where I include Companies which is a belongsToMany Relationship

Unique, and constraint dont do much they were attempts, paranoid worked though. I was able to fetch deletedAt records then.

````
export function getStudent(req, res, next) {
  Students.find({
    where: {
      id: req.params.id
    },
    order: [
      [{model: Addresses}, 'id', 'DESC'],
      [{model: Companies}, 'id', 'DESC'],
    ],
    include: [{model: Schools},
              {model: ClassificationTypes},
              {model: Companies,
                as: 'Companies',
                paranoid: false,
                through: { paranoid: false, unique: false, constraints: false }
              },
              {model: Drivers,
                as: 'Drivers'},
              {model: Addresses,
                as: 'Addresses',
                through: { paranoid: false },
                include: [{model: AddressTypes},
                          {model: States,
                          paranoid: false }]
              }
            ]
  }).then((students) => {
    return res.json(students);
  }).catch((err) => {
    res.sendStatus(500);
    next(err);
  });
}


Here are my models: 


export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const CompaniesStudents = sequelize.define('CompaniesStudents', {
    companyId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    studentId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    extraFees: DataTypes.FLOAT,
    createdAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    deletedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    }
  }, {
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: true,
  }
);
  return CompaniesStudents;
};
```
```js
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Companies = sequelize.define('Companies', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.STRING,
    phone: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    deletedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    }
  }, {
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: true,
  }
);

  Companies.associate = (models) => {
    Companies.belongsToMany(models.Drivers, {through: 'CompaniesDrivers', as: 'Drivers', foreignKey: 'companyId', otherKey: 'driverId'});
    Companies.belongsToMany(models.Students, {through: 'CompaniesStudents', as: 'Students', foreignKey: 'companyId', otherKey: 'studentId'});
    Companies.belongsToMany(models.Zones, {through: 'CompaniesZones', as: 'Zones', foreignKey: 'companyId', otherKey: 'zoneId'});
    Companies.belongsToMany(models.User, {through: 'CompaniesUsers', as: 'Users', foreignKey: 'companyId', otherKey: 'userId'});
    Companies.belongsToMany(models.Addresses, {through: 'CompaniesAddresses', as: 'Addresses', foreignKey: 'companyId', otherKey: 'addressId'});
  };

  return Companies;
};



export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Students = sequelize.define('Students', {
    studentIdentification: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
    schoolId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Schools',
          key: 'id'
        }
    },
    classificationTypeId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          references: {
            model: 'ClassificationTypes',
            key: 'id',
          }
      },
    zoneId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Zones',
          key: 'id'
        }
    },
    desiredPickUpTime: DataTypes.DATE,
    desiredDropOffTime: DataTypes.DATE,
    createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    deletedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE
    }
  }, {
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: true,
  }
);
  Students.associate = (models) => {
    Students.belongsTo(models.ClassificationTypes, { foreignKey: 'classificationTypeId'});
    Students.belongsTo(models.Schools, {foreignKey: 'schoolId'});
    Students.belongsTo(models.Zones, {foreignKey: 'zoneId'});
    Students.belongsToMany(models.Companies, {through: 'CompaniesStudents', as: 'Companies', foreignKey: 'studentId', otherKey: 'companyId'});
    Students.belongsToMany(models.Drivers, {through: 'DriversStudents', as: 'Drivers', foreignKey: 'studentId', otherKey: 'driverId'});
    Students.belongsToMany(models.Addresses, {through: 'StudentsAddresses', as: 'Addresses', foreignKey: 'studentId', otherKey: 'addressId'});
  };

  return Students;
};
````

### I expect all records to return, whether they are soft deleted or not.

### Only the Last record pertaining it is returned

Here is a example of two different companies a student has belonged to
Here are the records:
[image]

```
"Companies": [
        {
            "id": 19,
            "name": "Suspect Icecream truck",
            "description": "",
            "phone": "21312314",
            "email": "koawewa",
            "createdAt": "2018-03-20T19:41:03.578Z",
            "updatedAt": "2018-03-20T19:41:16.500Z",
            "deletedAt": null,
            "CompaniesStudents": {
                "companyId": 19,
                "studentId": 6,
                "extraFees": null,
                "createdAt": "2018-03-20T20:05:03.239Z",
                "updatedAt": "2018-03-20T20:05:03.239Z",
                "deletedAt": null
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 18,
            "name": "Karans Pickup Company",
            "description": "",
            "phone": "917321312",
            "email": "a21@yasd.com",
            "createdAt": "2018-03-20T19:40:39.012Z",
            "updatedAt": "2018-03-20T19:40:54.042Z",
            "deletedAt": null,
            "CompaniesStudents": {
                "companyId": 18,
                "studentId": 6,
                "extraFees": null,
                "createdAt": "2018-03-20T19:42:50.399Z",
                "updatedAt": "2018-03-20T19:42:50.399Z",
                "deletedAt": "2018-03-20T19:43:02.784Z"
            }
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use findAll as per documentation `find` is an alias for `findOne`.

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findOne

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll

Comment: Thats confusing, I have yet to try it but the only thing thats returning one instance is my 'Student' instance, whereas my includes : [Companies, Addresses] should show an array of all of the related instances. Isn't find/findOne still acceptable as it only generates in the sql query a select 1 from 'Students' where student id = :someId' on the outside. Whereas it will still do a inner left join on its associated records (companies, addresses)

Answer (score 0):

I realise this question is already over 2 years old, however, I recently stumbled onto this same issue and I would like to share the solution I found.

The problem resides in that Sequelize, as of v6.3.5, still doesn't directly support duplicate entries from through tables when using BelongToMany associations.

The issue has been already [raised](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3493), and is from there that I got the idea for my solution.

Basically, what you want to do is to substitute your M:N relationship with two 1:N. In Sequelize, that means that instead of declaring a relation like `A.belongsToMany(B, {through: 'C'})`, you declare `A.hasMany(C)`, `C.belongsTo(A)`, `B.hasMany(C)`, `C.belongsTo(B)`. Of course, this also requires to explicitly declare the C model, instead of having it automatically declared by the BelongsToMany relation. This is actually hinted at in the Sequelize [documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html#using-one-to-many-relationships-instead).

Applied to your case, for one of your BelongsToMany relations it would be then:

#### Companies Model (A)

```js
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Companies = sequelize.define('Companies', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.STRING,
    phone: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: true,
  }
);

  Companies.associate = (models) => {
    Companies.hasMany(models.CompaniesStudents, {foreignKey: 'companyId');
  };

  return Companies;
};
```

#### Students Model (B)

```js
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Students = sequelize.define('Students', {
    studentIdentification: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
    desiredPickUpTime: DataTypes.DATE,
    desiredDropOffTime: DataTypes.DATE,
  }, {
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: true,
  }
);

  Students.associate = (models) => {
    Students.hasMany(models.CompaniesStudents, {foreignKey: 'studentId'});
  };

  return Students;
};
```

#### Through table model (C)

```js
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const CompaniesStudents = sequelize.define('CompaniesStudents', {
    companyId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    studentId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    extraFees: DataTypes.FLOAT,
  }, {
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: true,
  }
);

  CompaniesStudents.associate = (models) => {
    CompaniesStudents.belongsTo(models.Companies, {foreignKey: 'companyId'});
    CompaniesStudents.belongsTo(models.Students, {foreignKey: 'studentId'});
  };

  return CompaniesStudents;
};
```

This way, to obtain the list of associated companies when querying Students, including "duplicated" entries, your query would be:

```js
Students.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: CompaniesStudents, 
    include: Companies
  }]
});
```

Which would return elements in the form

```js
{
  'id': 1,
  'CompaniesStudents': [
    {
      'companyId': 20,
      'studentId': 1,
      'extraFees': 100,
      'Companies': {'id': 20}
    }, {
      'companyId': 20,
      'studentId': 1,
      'extraFees': 200,
      'Companies': {'id': 20}
    }
  ]
}
```

Of course, you will have to add the corresponding associations for all the other relations you have, as well as the explicit models for the through tables.